# Returning Specific String found in text

Tags: r, regex, string, text-mining, data-manipulation

I have the following column in a df

```
c("I love bananas and apples.",
  "I hate apples and pears.",
  "I love to eat food.",
  "I hate lettuce and bananas")
```

and I have a vector of fruit

```
fruit <- c("apples", "bananas", "pears")
```

I know using str_detect  can return `TRUE` or `FALSE` per observation using

```
str_detect(df$text, paste(fruit, collapse='|'))
```

but what I would like is a column that has the variables that matched up, like the following

```
"I love bananas and apples."       "bananas","apples"
"I hate apples and pears."         "apples","pears"
"I love to eat food."              
"I hate lettuce and bananas."      "bananas"
```

is there a way to accomplish this? Is this outside the str_detect domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sapply(v, function(s){
    toString(unlist(lapply(fruit, function(f){
        if(grepl(f, s)) f
    })))
},
USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "apples, bananas" "apples, pears"   ""                "bananas"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all` to extract all the 'fruit' elements from the 'text' column in a `list`, loop through the `list` with `map` and `paste` (`toString`) them together to create the 'newtext' column

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate(newtext = map_chr(str_extract_all(text,     
      str_c(fruit, collapse='|')), ~toString(unique(.x)))
```

Comment: This works, however, I noticed there are few sentences where the person wrote about bananas twice, like "I love bananas. bananas are the best", and I get "bananas, bananas" once running your code. Is there a way to filter it down to just unique values and have "bananas" come up only once?

Comment: @Jacob That is easy to deal with. Check my update